# typescript typeguard make type of instance never (unexpected behavior)

Tags: typescript

When type checking is performed through type guard, it become `never` type outside the conditional statement.

You can test [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiBOBXAlgFwKbQN4ChrQDtEBbALkJICN14BuPaYAewIlSWFSfgAoiyKxavACU2BvlQALZBAB0-aAF5B9fAF8cm0JBgBBAA4GQmdAA8MBACYwEKDOPzNW7RJ258S5fsLG58%20BCIBjSexCJq0Jra4FDQAEJgBElg0OaWNnBIaJj%20jCxsHFy8-N5UNH4S0EEhJSQRDNE4OM5s0DnEMCoA2gToAO7QhsboPACMIgA0hAMJKcnjAAwiALr0LQWojCAsmCo8HRDkdjndK2JKAHyO0PDoqIjwBO0YnXLEYAYHr8rXefjIABm0G%206GI7RcSWA6CYwOGJkqAQCdweTxmg3how6CnqkQ0aRAEEwQJBHQhbChMOBiWSyURSNu90ezz6gxpKVBxBx4TxUSqKOZ6LmtLAnO5DQ0DU0Gxc7QgmOUpNex2yGBE5DJsiGRhMvxuArRmshBGhsO1I3o0taW1k7OSis5Kvs6HVLzBcuFKT1eQNzyNFJNVM9yUtzWt212ACYHYcnadzt6GL63W8Pl8yVcbgDgQd5Tqsa8RPSkcnWeaTGL%20BKAuoCUT2jnbfNRR0i1nkUy0WW7S3XuLeZoS52WbMe5XcY0pTggA)

```js
class Fruite {
  num: number;
  constructor(num: number) {
    this.num = num;
  }
}
class Apple extends Fruite {
  constructor(num: number) {
    super(num);
  }
}
class Banana extends Fruite {
  constructor(num: number) {
    super(num);
  }
}

const items = [new Apple(1), new Banana(10)];

const clone = (items: Fruite[]) => {
  return items.map(item => {
    if (item instanceof Apple) {
      return new Apple(item.num);
    } else if (item instanceof Banana) {
      return new Banana(item.num); // works well
    }
    return new Banana(item.num); // works well
  });
}

// ---- ERROR PART ----

const isApple = (item: Fruite): item is Apple => {
  return item instanceof Apple;
}

const isBanana = (item: Fruite): item is Banana => {
  return item instanceof Banana;
}

const clone2 = (items: Fruite[]) => {
  return items.map(item => {
    if (isApple(item)) {
      return new Apple(item.num);
    } else if (isBanana(item)) {
      return new Banana(item.num); // item is never !
    }
    return new Banana(item.num); // item is never !
  });
}
```

Why does the typescript determine the item as `never`?

Comment: [Classes are generally compared structurally](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#relationships-between-classes), so the compiler thinks that it is impossible for a value to be of type `Banana` without it also being of type `Apple`, since they are structurally identical.   The fix here would be to make them differ in structure (give them some differing properties) or add a `private`/`protected` field to them, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ7ygw). Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: thank you so much, would you please post your comment as answer?  
I will accept it.

Comment: Yes, I will do so as soon as I can, probably tomorrow (it is my bedtime now, ).

Comment: when I changed the type of **isApple isBanana** to **boolean** it worked for me. I think this happens because the current type describes only a specific scenario (item is Banana, for ex.) that doesn't necessarily happens (when you send an Apple item) hence the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Apple` and `Banana` are [structurally](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) identical, and since the TypeScript type system is largely structural and not [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system), it considers the two types equivalent.  That is, the fact that `Apple` and `Banana` have two different *declarations* does not mean that TypeScript considers them to be different *types*.  So if you write code where types are checked structurally, the compiler will decide that if something is an `Apple` then it must be a `Banana` and vice versa.

In your `clone` function, you are directly performing [an `instanceof` type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#instanceof-narrowing) check.  And `instanceof` narrowing compares types *nominally* and not structurally, because that's usually what people want.

On the other hand, when you refactored this check into [user-defined type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) `isApple()` and `isBanana()`, such nominal narrowing only happens inside the bodies of these functions.  The return type of the function, `item is Apple` or `item is Banana` doesn't convey any such special nominal flavor to the callers, so the type checker does the standard structural type check.  And so, inside `clone2`, the compiler thinks it is impossible for `item` to be a `Banana` if it is not an `Apple`.  And you get an error.

(Yes, these two forms of type checking aren't fully consistent with each other.  This is intentional; see [microsoft/TypeScript#33481](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33481) for more information.)

---

Anyway, generally speaking, you'll have better results if you make sure any two types that are meant to be different should differ *structurally*, by adding differing members to them.  For example:

```
class Apple extends Fruite {
  readonly type = "Apple";
  constructor(num: number) {
    super(num);
  }
}
class Banana extends Fruite {
  readonly type = "Banana";
  constructor(num: number) {
    super(num);
  }
}
```

Now both classes have a `type` property of differing string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  This clears up the problem with `clone2()`:

```
const clone2 = (items: Fruite[]) => {
  return items.map(item => {
    if (isApple(item)) {
      return new Apple(item.num);
    } else if (isBanana(item)) {
      return new Banana(item.num); // okay
    }
    return new Banana(item.num); // okay
  });
}
```

Again, just about any distinguishing property will work.  For classes you can add [a `private` or `protected` member](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#private-and-protected-members-in-classes) and as long as they have separate declarations the classes will be considered distinct (that is, `private`/`protected` properties are compared nominally and not structurally):

```
class Apple extends Fruite {
  private prop: undefined;
  constructor(num: number) {
    super(num);
  }
}
class Banana extends Fruite {
  private prop: undefined;
  constructor(num: number) {
    super(num);
  }
}
```

It's up to you how you want to distinguish your classes.  Ideally they would actually have distinct structures *naturally*, because you're using them for different purposes. Maybe a `Banana` has a `ripeness` property and a `removeFromBunch()` method, while an `Apple` has a `variety` property and a `keepTheDoctorAway()` method.  But that depends on your use cases.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.3#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiBOBXAlgFwKbQN4ChrQDtEBbALkJICN14BuPaYAewIlSWFSfgAoiyKxavACU2BvlQALZBAB0-aAF5B9fAF8cm0JBgBBAA4GQmdAA8MBACYwEKDOPzx0YKyxABPaKg8HMKgCJDY3QAtUYWNg4uXn5yfmExXHx8CEQ-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-EOed3G7hqD70buOnutRiOV6rDeZpAgATPevo2jUhIOk6YYMN+L7yAGQYxp+MwVla84Xj2IjNgiyEdjmY59jMxboKW5ZRjhI74YRKTERq77amRhbQAA9Jx0BMAA1mAHgUQO+5Dix9HsROXE8fxgnLFOqxAA)